# index out of bounds exception java

Tags: java, debugging, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

So the error message is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at FcfsScheduler.sortArrival(FcfsScheduler.java:77)
at FcfsScheduler.computeSchedule(FcfsScheduler.java:30)
at ScheduleDisks.main(ScheduleDisks.java:33)
```

with my code as

```
public void sortArrival(List<Request> r)
{
    int pointer = 0;
    int sProof = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        if(r.get(pointer).getArrivalTime()<r.get(pointer+1).getArrivalTime())
        {
            Request r1 = r.get(pointer);
            Request r2 = r.get(pointer+1);
            r.set(pointer, r2);
            r.set(pointer+1, r1);
        }
        else
        {
            sProof++;
        }
        ++pointer;
        if(pointer>r.size()-2)
        {
            pointer=0;
            sProof=0;
        }
        if(sProof>=r.size()-2)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is at

```
if(r.get(pointer).getArrivalTime()<r.get(pointer+1).getArrivalTime())
```

but I think the array index is checked ok with the code after the increment of pointer. Is it an array out of bounds exception or something else? Normally, the error is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when it is the array. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: This error is showing because your `ArrayList` is empty.!!

Comment: Try debugging your code using debugger, you can get exactly where and how error is occurring.

Comment: you should check pointer+1 against the size of r in your while decleration to avoid this error. also, checking that r is not null and not empty may be a good idea.

Comment: List you have input is empty

Comment: This is tangential to the exception, but if you are trying to sort your List, a better approach is having the Request class implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) instead. You could then use Collections.sort(r).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734/608639)

Answer (score 6):

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

ArrayList is empty. It does not contain any element.

```
Index: 0, Size: 0.
```

You are trying to access it.So you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
if(r.size() == 0) && r.size() < pointer + 1)   //If ArrayList size is zero then simply return from method.
  return;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are passing in an empty array. You should do some validation on the inputs

```
if (r == null || r.size()==0){
   throw new RuntimeException("Invalid ArrayList");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array size is 0, you should initialize it correctly in order to iterate it.