# Bus Seat Booking Select and deselect issue with position

Tags: java, android, arrays, gridview, android-recyclerview

I am working on a bus booking app. I created seat booking layout using Recyclerview and GridLayoutManager. Layout created properly. I have 4 seats in 1 row and 5 seats in the last row. So I used 5 column in GridLayoutManager. And middle column will be empty for space between 2 seats for walking. Now the problem is if I clicked on the 1st seat in will select 1s seat but image change of 5th seat. And I also set seat no in textview, so sometimes it shows correct seat no., sometimes it shows blank or sometimes wrong.

[This is My Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoHk7.png)

**SeatSelection Activity**

```
public class SeatSelection extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

RecyclerView recyclerView;
SeatAdapter seatAdapter;
List<SeatDetails> seatDetailsList;
TextView txtSeatNo;
ImageView imageView;
TextView fare;
public Bitmap seatIcon;
public Bitmap seatSelect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seat_selection);

    seatIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.seat_layout_screen_nor_avl);
    seatSelect = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.seat_layout_screen_nor_std);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 5);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    seatAdapter = new SeatAdapter(this, loadBustListSeats());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(seatAdapter);
}

public class SeatDetails {
    String name;
    boolean isBlank;
    boolean isSelected;

    public SeatDetails(String name, boolean isBlank, boolean isSelected)
    {                   
        this.name = name;
        this.isBlank = isBlank;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public List<SeatDetails> loadBustListSeats() {

    seatDetailsList = new ArrayList<SeatDetails>();
    int seatSerialNumber = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
        if (isBlankSeat(i)) {
            seatDetailsList.add(new SeatDetails("", true, false));
        } else {
            if (i == 0) {
                seatDetailsList.add(new SeatDetails("A",  true, false));
            } else if (i == 1) {
                seatDetailsList.add(new SeatDetails("B", true, false));
            } else {
                seatDetailsList.add(new SeatDetails(String.valueOf(seatSerialNumber), true, false));
                seatSerialNumber = seatSerialNumber + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return seatDetailsList;
}


public boolean isBlankSeat(int i) {
    if ((60 - (i - 1)) < 5)
        return false;
    else
        return i % 5 == 2 ;
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


}



public void seatSelected(int pos)
{
    charge = charge + amt;
    imageView.setImageBitmap(seatSelect);
    txtSeatNo.setText(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName());
    fare.setText(String.valueOf(charge));
    seatDetailsList.remove(pos);
    seatDetailsList.add(pos, new SeatDetails(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName(), true, true));
    seatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void seatDeselected(int pos)
{
    charge = charge - amt;
    imageView.setImageBitmap(seatIcon);
    fare.setText(String.valueOf(charge));
    seatDetailsList.remove(pos);
    seatDetailsList.add(pos, new SeatDetails(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName(), true, false));
    seatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public class SeatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{


    class ViewHolderOriginal extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textView;
        ViewHolderOriginal(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);


        }
    }

    class ViewHolderBlank extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ViewHolderBlank(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }

    }


    private  Context cntx;
    public SeatAdapter(Context context, List<SeatDetails> list){
        cntx = context;
        seatDetailsList = list;
    }

    // 0= Original view 1= Blank View
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if((getItemCount()-(position-1))<5)
            return 0;
        else
            return position % 5 == 2 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 60;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (viewType == 1)
            return new ViewHolderBlank(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_blank, parent, false));
        else
            return new ViewHolderOriginal(inflater.inflate(R.layout.seatrow_grid, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ViewHolderBlank) {

        } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderOriginal) {
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SeatDetails seatDetails = seatDetailsList.get(position);

                    if (seatDetails.isSelected){
                        seatDeselected(position);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        seatSelected(position);

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the value of `pos` in `seatDetailsList.get(pos)` is off by one. Could you add exception stacktrace to the question?  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462649/index-out-of-bounds-exception-java

Comment: Ok i changed 'for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)' to 'for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++)' and it solves crashing issue. But still i have problem in selecting and deselecting seats. @Timir

Comment: Please explain your function: `public boolean isBlankSeat(int i) ` It seems you're hardcoding your blank seat checking

Comment: Yes it is for blank seats which is 3rd seat of row. And i want that blank space it indicate walking space. @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

Comment: How many seats you want to create? Is that value fixed?

Comment: Yes Total 49 first two A and B then 1 to 47. And last row have all 5 seats visible

Comment: And i dont know why if i select 1st seat then it is selecting 1st seat as i seen in debugger but it changes image of 1st seat of 2nd row.

Comment: 61 or 49? Your function are using 60 as item count, and your loop execute 61 times `for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++)`

Comment: I need total 49 seats but there is also blank seats so i written 60

Comment: Yeah loop executes 61 but if i write i < 60 then it is crashing onClick last seat because of IndexOutOfBound

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple problems should be fixed and improve

Let review this code for selecting a seat:

```
public void seatSelected(int pos)
{
    charge = charge + amt;
    imageView.setImageBitmap(seatSelect);
    txtSeatNo.setText(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName());
    fare.setText(String.valueOf(charge));
    seatDetailsList.remove(pos);
    seatDetailsList.add(pos, new SeatDetails(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName(), true, true));
    seatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Suppose your list are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, and you're going to add item at `pos = 3`.

First you are calling: `seatDetailsList.remove(pos);` -> Your list becomes `[0, 1, 2, 4]`.

Then you are calling

```
seatDetailsList.add(pos, new SeatDetails(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName(), true, true));
```

In this method call, you're get `seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName()` from list, the current `pos = 3` items in the list is `4` hen you end up add a seat with number `4` to the list like this:

`[0, 1, 2, 4, 4]` not `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` as you expected.

Then imagine you're selecting the last seat in your list. If you remove the last index (`4`), then the access to get `seatDetailsList.get(pos)` will throw exception because you're accessing the memory outside the list (`ArrayOutOfBoundIndexException`).

So you could fix this simply by modify the current state of the seat, instead of remove and re-add them.

Try this:

```
public void seatSelected(int pos)
{
    charge = charge + amt;
    imageView.setImageBitmap(seatSelect);
    txtSeatNo.setText(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName());
    fare.setText(String.valueOf(charge));
    //seatDetailsList.remove(pos);
    //seatDetailsList.add(pos, new SeatDetails(seatDetailsList.get(pos).getName(), true, true));
    seatDetailList.get(pos).setIsSelected(true);

    seatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Try doing the same thing with the `seatDeselected` function, and change the loop to `for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)`

**Edit**

```
class ViewHolderOriginal extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView; // Add this as internal property

    ViewHolderOriginal(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);


    }
}
```

And in your listener:

```
   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SeatDetails seatDetails = seatDetailsList.get(position);

                if (seatDetails.isSelected){
                    seatDeselected(position);
                    holder.getImageView().setImageBitmap(seatSelect); // Modify state

                }
                else
                {
                    seatSelected(position);
                    holder.getImageView().setImageBitmap(seatSelect); // Modify state
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes now now bug ratio goes down and looks perfect when selecting and deselecting as i m showing seat no. in textview. But it is not changing icon of selected seat.

Comment: You should update your viewHolder after select/deselect seat

Comment: Check my image in question. If i select on any seat, it will change icon of same seat every time as shown in image.