# 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:Index 10 out of bounds for length 10' error?

Tags: java, arrays

The above code is for inserting an element in an array. I tried changing the length of
an array to 9 but still the issue persist.

```
public class Array1 {
    public static int[] insertX (int n,int x,int pos,int arr[]) {
        
        int newarr[] = new int[n+1];
      
        for(int i=0; i<i+1;i++) {
            if(i < pos -1) {
                newarr[i]=arr[i];
            }
            else if(i==pos-1) {
                newarr[i]=x;
            }
            else
            {
                newarr[i]= arr[i-1];
            }
            
        }
        return newarr;
        
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int n=10;
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; 
        System.out.println("Initial array"+ " " + Arrays.toString(arr));
        int x=50;
        int pos =5;
        arr = insertX(n,x,pos,arr);
        System.out.println("Array with inserted number"+ " " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

}
```

Comment: `i<i+1` will always be true, your loop will never stop

Comment: Actually, if it weren't for the exception being thrown, the loop would stop when `i` gets to the maximum `int` value.  It should probably say `i < n + 1` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your loop end condition:

```
for(int i=0; i<newarr.length;i++)
```

Condition `i<i+1` is always true, so your lop will never end.

Example:

- i=0; then 0<0+1;
- i=2; then 2<2+1;

When the `i` index will reach 10, there is no value in `newarr` for this index. Max index is 9.. This will cause [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462649/index-out-of-bounds-exception-java).

Its safer to use `array.length`, this way you will not make this exception again.

Comment: Got it. Will make changes as per your answer.